# How to manually pass host name to ansible tower template at runtime

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I am have a requirement like passing a server hostname at runtime to ansible tower template. the issue i faced is we dont know the hostname before running the template so we cant configure hostname in the ansible tower inventory. I tired googling but haven't found a solution yet.

my main.yaml file starting will be looking like this

```
- name: Execution server
  hosts: <hostname>
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
```

the erroer i am getting is

```
1 plays in main.yml
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: <hostname>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `target_host` variable. I like setting a default with this

```yaml
- name: Execution server
  hosts: "{{ target_host | default('all') }} "
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
```

Define `target_host` in a job template's limit:

[image]

Comment: we can set the target_host but the issue is we only get the host name at the time of triggering the template. so wont be able to set the limit beforehand

Comment: what is the ansible-playbook command you're trying to run in tower?? my impression was `ansible-playbook -l <server>` (assuming inventory path is set in ansible.cfg)

Comment: no . we have another setup we use awx cli for calling the template and passing the required values as variables